# Intuitively understanding the probability that one of the two coins is a head given that there is a tail

Tags: probability

Suppose that I flip two coins without showing you the result. Now, I tell you that one of the coins is T. The probability that the other coin is H is
$$
\mathbf{P}[HT, TH| \text{at least one } T] = \frac{\mathbf{P}[HT, TH]}{\mathbf{P}\text{[at least one } T]} = \frac{2}{3}
$$

But the thing is, a fair coin should always yield $50\%$ for each flip. I understand that the two coins are no longer independent, but can someone provide me of an intuitive explanation of why this is?

Comment: You may enjoy reading up on the [Boy or Girl paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_or_Girl_paradox) and related links.

Comment: Wow, didn't know they had a wikipedia page dedicated for this.

Comment: The answer is not as clear cut as it seems, unless additional assumptions are made on how the "*I tell you that...*" information was collected. See [this part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_or_Girl_paradox#Second_question) in particular: "*Specifically, Gardner argued that a "failure to specify the randomizing procedure" could lead readers to interpret the question in two distinct ways*".

Comment: I think the simplest intuition is this.  1) there are 4 possible outcomes.  2) 1 off them has no tails.  3) The remaining 3 do.  4) of the remaining 3, 1 of them has 2 tails.  5) the remaining 2 out of three have heads.  6) of the three outcomes with tails of which 2 will have a head, each outcome is equally likely.  Now, to explain the 50% each flip... it *was* 50%.  But we removing one 1/4 of the fair options leaving only 3/4 of the option.  1/2 it is tails, 1/4 it is heads and the other is tails, and 1/4 it is heads and the other is heads and this option is removed.

Comment: @dxiv So, from reading the article, I guess I could understand this so-called paradox stemming from the wording rather than it being a probabilistic anomaly. I understand that if I were to ask "given there are two coins and that one of them is a T, what is the probability that the other is a H?" instead, this would get rid of the confusion. But then again, it wouldn't be so much of a brainteaser than a bland _Intro to Probability_ exercise question.

Comment: @Astaboom Right. There is a degree of imprecision in the original wording. If stated as "*not* both coins are H", instead, then all ambiguity is removed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The paradox arises simply because there are two ways to flip one head and one tail (the most likely outcome of flipping two coins) but only one way to flip two tails.

As a generalisation, consider flipping 24 coins and then revealing that there was a tail. What is the probability that at least one other coin was a head? Out of the $2^{24}-1=16777215$ 24-coin flips that contain a tail, only one of them contains 24 tails, leaving the conditional probability that at least one coin is a head as $\frac{16777214}{16777215}$ – in other words, virtually certain.

Answer (score 1):

Just list the possibilities.  Initially you have $HH,HT, TH, TT.$  You have ruled out $HH$, so you have three possibilities left.  In two of them the non-tails coin is heads.

Answer (score 0):

There are four possibilities: $HH, HT, TH, TT.$ With the information that one coin is tails, you've removed the first one and are left with $HT, TH, TT.$

Two out of three of these possibilities have the other coin being heads.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Omega = \{H,T\}^2$, $\mathcal F=2^\Omega$, and $\mathbb P$ be uniform on the atoms of $\Omega$. Define $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ by 
$$ X(\omega) = 
\begin{cases}
0,& \omega = (T,T)\\
1,& \omega = (T,H)\text{ or } \omega=(H,T)\\
2,& \omega = (H,H).
\end{cases}
$$
That is, $X$ is the number of heads in a given outcome, where the experiment is flipping a fair coin twice. Then 
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X = 1\mid X\leqslant 1) &= \frac{\mathbb P(X=1, X\leqslant 1)}{\mathbb P(X\leqslant 1)}\\
&=\frac{\mathbb P(X=1)}{\mathbb P(X\leqslant 1)}\\
&= \frac{\mathbb P(\{T,H\}, \{H,T\} ) }{\mathbb P(\{(T,T),(T,H),(H,T)\}}\\
&= \frac{\mathbb P(\{T,H\})+\mathbb P(\{H,T\})}{\mathbb P(\{T,T\})+\mathbb P(\{T,H\})+\mathbb P(\{H,T\})}\\
&= \frac{2\cdot\frac14}{3\cdot\frac14}\\
&=\frac 23.
\end{align}